# techniques for dealing with large svg images

Tags: html, svg

I want to let the svg expand out fully beyond the viewport so none of the shapes are squashed together.  I'll then add panning and zooming which I know how to do.

But how can I let the svg expand out fully so none of the shapes are squashed together and the text labels all display their text without overlapping each other?

With my example, the svg is still trying to fit all its content into the svg viewport.  I want to to let it expand outside of the viewport so nothing overlaps and use zoom and pan to view the image.

These large images are the exception and not the norm.

I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/6z1sd48r/1/) that illustrates the problem.

At the moment my viewBox is set to:

```
<svg opacity="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 817 664" style="opacity: 1;">
  <!-- child nodes -->
</svg>
```

Comment: How do you define "expand out fully"?  SVGs are vector graphics, so there's no "full size" concept. Also, many have inherently overlapping components, so no amount of zooming will alleviate overlapping.

Comment: Maybe you should try to organise the information differently. For example for the text you may try to use tooltips. Alternatively you may dynamically manipulate the viewBox when dragging over the SVG.

Comment: I would suggest to use clipping like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883003/5770014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more than anything a design problem. 
One alternative solution to what you have would be to *use some method to change the `viewBox` of your SVG and rotate the text to avoid overlapping*, more or less like this. In this case I'm using an input type range to change the `viewBox` but you may decide to choose a different solution.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

let A = -1200;
let B = 1200;

let hexArray = []

function drawHexagon(r){  
  let points = "";
   for( let i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
        let a = i * ( Math.PI / 3 );
        let x = (r * Math.cos( a - Math.PI/2 )).toFixed(3);
        let y = (r * Math.sin( a  - Math.PI/2)).toFixed(3);
        points += `${x},${y} `;
      }
  return points;
}

function useHex(theParent,pos){
   let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
   use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#theHex');
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
   //use.setAttribute("title",'x value:'+pos.x);
   theParent.appendChild(use);
   hexArray.push(use);
  
   drawText('x value:'+pos.x,pos)
}

function drawText(val,pos){
  let txt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
  txt.textContent = val;
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",`translate(0,30) rotate(-75  ${pos.x},${pos.y})`);
  textParent.appendChild(txt);
}

function connector(parent,p){
  let path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
  let d =`M${p.x},${p.y}C${p.x},125 0,125 0,0`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
  parent.appendChild(path);
}

for(let x = A; x <= B; x+=50){
  let pos = {x:x,y:250}
  useHex(useParent,pos);
  connector(connectors,pos);
}



itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `${itr.value} -50 1200 550`); 
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
use {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000;
}

#itr {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

#connectors path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}

text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<input id="itr" type="range" min = "-1225" max = "25" value = "-600" />

<svg id="svg" viewBox="-600 -50 1200 550" style="--display:block;">
<defs><polygon  id="theHex"  points="21.651,-12.500 21.651,12.500 0.000,25.000 -21.651,12.500 -21.651,-12.500 -0.000,-25.000 "  ></polygon>
</defs> 
<g id="connectors">
  
</g>
<g id="useParent">
<use xlink:href="#theHex" y="0"  />
</g>
<g id="textParent">
  
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You've set me on the right path.  I have a plan :).  Thanks