# how to add horizontal scroll to svg child elements under g tag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scrollable

[image]

```
<svg width="1200" height="1200"><g><g class="flow-group"><g class="node-group" id="parent-node-fb-elem-id-3" data-id="fb-elem-id-3" data-x="192" data-y="95" transform="translate(192, 95)"><rect id="state" width="270" height="240" fill="#fff" cursor="all-scroll" stroke="#9bc8ff" filter="url(#dropShadowv-21195304394)" rx="15" ry="15"></rect><g class="onEntry" id="onEntry-fb-elem-id-3" data-id="fb-elem-id-3" width="270" height="42"><rect x="0" id="onentry-1574072990" rx="10" ry="10" y="51" height="42" width="42" class="love" draggable="true" fill="#6cf0df"></rect><rect x="45" id="onentry-1574072992" rx="10" ry="10" y="51" height="42" width="42" class="love" draggable="true" fill="#277270"></rect><rect x="90" id="onentry-1574072994" rx="10" ry="10" y="51" height="42" width="42" class="love" draggable="true" fill="#ec02d9"></rect><rect x="135" id="onentry-1574072996" rx="10" ry="10" y="51" height="42" width="42" class="love" draggable="true" fill="#89ddfc"></rect><rect x="180" id="onentry-1574072998" rx="10" ry="10" y="51" height="42" width="42" class="love" draggable="true" fill="#c8791e"></rect><rect x="225" id="onentry-1574073026" rx="10" ry="10" y="51" height="42" width="42" class="love" draggable="true" fill="#3e727f"></rect></g></g></g></g></svg>
```

i wanted to add horizontal scroll to svg list comes under g tags

Comment: i am not using any html tags . it's fully svg elements only. i tried to add css property ie-
.onEntryaction {overflow-x: scroll !important; width:100px; fill:red }

 it's adding scroll to "onEntryaction" . but not working scroll behaviour

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996459/techniques-for-dealing-with-large-svg-images/53997524#53997524

Comment: Please look at image reference attached to this issues, actually i want to add scroll under  "g" tag  if space occupied by number of rectangular boxes is greater than width of "g" section

Comment: add clippath to the `g`, add drag listener to the `g` and modify the `transform` `translate` `x` attribute on drag

Comment: no browser supports scollbars under <g> tags. scrollbars are a HTML-only thing.

Comment: Like @DmitriiG. wrote, I would also suggest to use clipping, similar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883003/5770014).